# Using Fuzzy and Prefix match with Span_multi in ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-dsl, pylucene

My use case is to have multiple phrases/words highlighted in a field that is retrieved based on fuzzy and prefix matching. For this I have currently used span_near to handle phrases and span_multi for allowing the use for fuzziness in my phrase terms. I also need to use prefix_length so fuzzy is only allowed for the characters after prefix match but span_multi does not allow more than one multi term query. Is there any other way this can be done?

```
    "query":{
    "bool":{
        "should":[{
  "span_near": {
    "clauses": [
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "comment": {
                "fuzziness": "5",
                "value": "Beata"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
        {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "comment": {
                "fuzziness": "5",
                "value": "Rosenane"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "in_order": False,
  }},{
  "span_near": {
    "clauses": [
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "comment": {
                "fuzziness": "5",
                "value": "Christna"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "in_order": False,
  }}]
}
},
    "highlight" : {
    "fields" : {
      "comment" : { "pre_tags" : ["<temp>"], "post_tags" : ["</temp>"],
                   "number_of_fragments" : 0
                  }

  }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey so it was working with

```
"comment": {
                "fuzziness": "5",
                "value": "Rosenane",
                "prefix_match":3
              }
```